# update tqdm parallelly within async function

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have written a program to upload data to azure storage. As the file size is quite big, I want a progress bar to see the upload status. But the progress bar update happens sequentially and not w.r.t dynamic data.

```
with open(source, "rb") as data:
    await client.upload_blob(
                    name=destination,
                    data=data,
                    overwrite=True,
                    length=size,
                )
```

What I want is to get `data.tell()` pointer shared in real time to update the tqdm parallelly.

Any direction towards the solution is appreciated.

Comment: [`progress_hook`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-upload-blob) argument can add a callback that can update the tqdm bar, maybe through a lambda, or a local defined function.